# Synchronized Maps like Hashtable, ConcurrentHashMap etc will lock only Map Objects or even the Objects stored as Values in Map

Tags: java, object, dictionary, locking

Consider below Map

```
Map<String, Employee> m = new Hashtable<String, Employee>();
```

Even though the Map is synchronized and can be accessed by only one Thread at time, How about the Object stored as value in Map?
once each thread gets employee Object, each thread can update it  and this update is not Thread safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronized data structures do not magically render the instances they contain thread safe. They can help for safe publication, however. You would have to make `Employee` thread safe yourself.

Also note that `ConcurrentHashMap` does not use a lock on the entire map, and can in many cases be accessed safely by multiple threads concurrently.